# Need Vimeo API for Upload from URL

Tags: php, api, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I am developing video streaming site and i am using vimeo server for host video's and vimeo has great set of API releases.
According to my requirement i want to upload video's also from youtube/Gdrive/Dropbox/Box/Onedrive etc. so Is there any way to upload video's from URL?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at Vimeo documentation they have an api endpoint called [Automatic (“pull”) uploads](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#automatic-pull-uploads) which takes the video from a URL which sounds like what you are looking for.